# Making a worksheet_selectionchange make different changes depending on the range I select?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have cells G8:G1000 setup to that when I select one of those cells it switches the words in the cell from Open -> Closed -> Blank

I'm trying to add another range E8:E1000 to switch between HyperCare -> Blank

But when I add the ElseIf after the Open & closed section I keep getting a Compile Error: Else without IF.

Please let me know if you have any ideas how I can solve this.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("g8:g1000")) Is Nothing Then
      Select Case Target.Value
      Case ""
        Target.Value = "Open"
      Case "Open"
        Target.Value = "Closed"
      Case "Closed"
        Target.Value = ""
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E8:E1000")) Is Nothing Then
      Select Case Target.Value
      Case ""
        Target.Value = "HyperCare"
      Case "HyperCare"
        Target.Value = ""
    End Select
    Range("A1").Select
    End If
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image: Excel Error and design]

As mentioned above, I'm expecting to click either cell range and change the value of the cells based on the if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot an End Select

```
...
    Case "Closed"
      Target.Value = ""
  End Select   '<-- that one
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E8:E1000")) Is Nothing Then
...
```

Comment: I'm such a dork lol! Thank you for this, I didn't realize I needed the end select right there!

Answer (score 0):

Although complie error is `Else without If`, it is actually a missing `End Select`. (`Sam` points the error first.)

For larger lists, avoid many `Case` statements as below. Storing rotations in an array makes maintenance easier, including reordering. Only one line needed to change target regardless of list size.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim aList
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G8:G1000")) Is Nothing Then
                aList = Array("", "Open", "Closed", "")
                .Value = aList(Application.Match(.Text, aList, 0))
                Range("A1").Select
            ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E8:E1000")) Is Nothing Then
                aList = Array("", "HyperCare", "")
                .Value = aList(Application.Match(.Text, aList, 0))
                Range("A1").Select
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this! That's a smart way to do it!